# python os.path.exists returns false

Tags: python

I am officially lost.. I have a trivial piece of python which checks whether a file exists. The path is stored in a dictionary.

When I execute next line of code, it returns false:

```
if not os.path.exists(self.parameters['icm_profile']):
    raise FileDoesNotExistError(PreprocessingErrors.FileNotPresent, "icm profile {} not found".format(self.parameters['icm_profile']))
```

When I copy THE EXACT STRING and execute the next line, it returns true:

```
if not os.path.exists("S:\\IAI\\Data\\Recipes\\BGD\\Inkjet\\LPI\\CMY_360x720dpi_2dpd_profilev6.icm"):
    print("aap")
```

Thus, then the path does exist.

There is no difference I can think of... What in gods name am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: What happens on `assert self.parameters['icm_profile'] == "S:\\IAI\\Data\\Recipes\\BGD\\Inkjet\\LPI\\CMY_360x720dpi_2dpd_profilev6.icm"`?

Comment: Your path contains quotation marks. Notice how it starts with `'"` and ends with `"'`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey right, something I am blind to the obvious I guess.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you've got an extra pair of quotes in there which could be causing you hassle. Try:

```
self.parameters['icm_profile'][1:-1]
```

Another approach mentioned by DeepSpace is to use

```
self.parameters['icm_profile'].strip('"')
```

Or if you're really paranoid

```
self.parameters['icm_profile'].strip('"').strip("'")
```

Comment: What happens if one day there will be no quotes? (we don't know where `self.parameters` is coming from). A better solution is `self.parameters.strip('"')`

Comment: Aha, that's it. Thanks a bunch!! I am quoting the path from the client application but that's not necessary then. I can remove it there, as adding the path to the dictionary (as a string) already adds the quotes. Thanks again, I overlooked that a 1000 times.... !

Comment: @DeepSpace on the other hand, `strip` might strip off *too many* quotation marks for some weird filnames. :)

Comment: I think it's one of those that you gotta assume you know the behaviour of within certain constraints, probably for the realm of unittesting